# snap-installed slack does not show icon in xfce panel

Tags: ubuntu, xfce

I used snap to install slack on ubuntu 18.04.

This is slack in the panel; it does not show the logo:

[image]

The icon shows up fine in the menu, though:

[image]

I'm wondering either how I can fix this or how I can file a bug report.